# ExtJS 7.3.1 modern - display static text in textfield

Tags: extjs, extjs7

I'm trying to display static text within a `textfield`, for example a `%` sign. Is there a way to do this? If I'm using the `tpl` or `html` property, the text gets displayed on a new line. It seems like there was a property `afterSubTpl` in classic, is there something similar for the modern toolkit?

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT**

I tried to achieve something like this:

[image: example]

The `%` should be statically visible behind the entered text and move if the length of the entered text increases.

Comment: May you provide some kind of "screenshot"?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution to display some text after the entered value. This will be working for all fields that extend from `Ext.field.Text`.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.overrides.field.Text', {
    override: 'Ext.field.Text',

    config: {
        suffix: null
    },

    setSuffix: function (suffix) {
        this.callParent(arguments);

        this.setBind({
            data: {
                value: `{${this.getBind().value.stub.path}}`
            }
        });

        let field = this.inputElement,
            tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
                `<div style="left: {value:this.getWidth}px; top: 0; position:absolute; pointer-events: none">${suffix}</div>`, {
                    getWidth: function (value) {
                        return field.getTextWidth(value) + 3;
                    }
                });
        this.setTpl(tpl);
    }
});
```

To use it you can do something like this:

```
xtype: 'textfield',
bind: {
    value: '{myProperty}'
},
suffix: '%'
```

Also a dynamic binding possible:

```
xtype: 'textfield',
bind: {
    value: '{myProperty}',
    suffix: '{mySuffix}'
}
```

Comment: You should be able to use the trigger for this. Search for `beforeInputElement` in `Ext.field.Text` to understand what I am talking about (gets the triggerGroup added).